# Broadcast mouse events to all nodes connected using node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, mouseevent, broadcast

Is there a way to broadcast mouse events such as mousedown, mouseup and mousemove to all nodes connected to the nodejs server? I am trying to replicated events at certain (x,y) coordinates. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is

### Client

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
   var data = extractMouseData(event); //extract data from event.
   io.emit('mousedown', data);
});

io.on('mousedown', function(data) {
   processMouseEvent(data);
});
```

### Server

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('mousedown', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('mousedown', data);
  });
});
```

Just implement `extractMouseData` and `processMouseEvent` functions and make them to do what you want to do and here you go.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation. So I should get the X,Y coordinates inside extractMouseData function? Is that right?

Comment: @Arihant yes get the from `extractMouseData` and use them in `processMouseEvent`

Comment: I am getting an error in console stating io.on is not a function. Clue?

Comment: @Arihant you need to do basic `socket.io` setup before using my sample http://socket.io/docs/